# Creating Excel Function: Average of Dynamic Range

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a list of 4000 different price values in one column. I want to calculate the average of the first X values in the column and display the result in cell "B21". The value of X can be changed and is located in cell "B20". How would I use excel functions to do this? Perhaps Average and Offset?

Comment: Usually a "need help" type of question is not a good question. In this case, I was glad I did nonetheless read it.

Answer (score 9):

This will do it:

```
=AVERAGE(A1:INDEX(A:A,B20))
```

Note that a 0 or blank in B20 will average the whole column. You could filter that out with an `IF` statement:

```
=IF(B20=0,"NA",AVERAGE(A1:INDEX(A:A,B20)))
```

As Barry mentioned in his comment, I chose `INDEX` because it's not as volatile as `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT`.

Comment: Yep, INDEX is preferable to INDIRECT and OFFSET because it's not as volatile

Answer (score 3):

How about:

**=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A1:A" & B20))**

Answer (score 2):

I'll throw my hat in the ring as well using the functions the op suggested.

```
=average(offset(A1,0,0,B20))
```

As Doug's comment this will also give an error with blanks or 0 in B20.

Gordon